# how to decide number of devices complete one task?

Tags: optaplanner

I have a business model. With a task, there is a list of selectable devices. How to determine the final device to complete the task through the optimization algorithm of optaplaner, which may be 1, 2, or more. and determine the start time and end time of the task according to the optimized equipment work time. Please give me a suggestion. Thank you!

```
@PlanningEntity(difficultyComparatorClass = TaskDifficultyComparator.class)
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Task extends TaskOrDevice {
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "deviceRange", "taskRange" }, graphType = PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED)
    private TaskOrDevice previousTaskOrDevice;
    @AnchorShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "previousTaskOrDevice")
    private DeviceInfo deviceInfo;
  
    @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = StartTimeUpdatingVariableListener.class,
            sources = { @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "previousTaskOrDevice") })
    private Long startTime; // In minutes
    private List<DeviceInfo> selectAbleDevices;
}
```

Comment: From your description, I understand you want each task to be assigned to 1 or more devices. What determines how many (and which) devices a task needs?

Comment: in my business model, each order have a tasklist ,so the order's delivery date effect the devices choose,please give some good idea,thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks for putting some light on other parts of the business model. Yet, the relationship between a single task and devices is still not clear to me. For example, can a task somehow require the usage of multiple different devices? How long will it need any device?